# Crash after QDeclarativeContext::setContextProperty()

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Please help me with my problem. 
I`m writing hybrid Qt/c++ & qml application and I encountered a strange problem. It crashing on initialization, while registating properties.

```
EventBridge::EventBridge(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    MainWindowInst->setContextProperty("EventBridge",this);
}

void MainWindow::setContextProperty(const QString &property, QObject *data)
{
    viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty(property,data); // viewer is QDeclarativeView
}
```

Comment: And none of the pointers are `NULL`?

Comment: Yes,I checked it three times

Comment: I suspect it's because of virtual function calls from constructor. Have you tried to move property binding out of constructors?

Comment: @Dcow: could you please show the backtrace for the crash?